# There is errer on ios device when executing firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter

There is an error when running on an iOS emulator from a flutter firebase
I don't know what the error is. Please help me.
[image]
[Error Log is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDD9x.png)

Comment: try to change the ios emulator

Comment: Maybe I use xcode 12.5 and Emulator uses 14.4 and this doesn't matter?

Comment: and i changed emulator but nothing diffrent

Comment: check your info.plist

Comment: do you possibly have to specify a targeted watchOS in Xcode?